# Write contents of immediate window to a text file

Tags: vba, immediate-window

I'm writing a macro which goes through a document and tries to parse it by Style. Right now, anything in the designated style is copied onto the immediate window. Is there a way to automate the macro further to move the text from the immediate window into a txt file? Otherwise, anyone using the macro would not be able to see the text unless they opened up VBA, correct?

Comment: How are you putting it into the immediate window?  Can you store it into a string variable instead and drop it into a text file when the process is completed?

Comment: ... or just pop it up in a form.

Comment: I don't understand why you would want to have the information first transit in the immediate window, and only then be written to a file from there. Why not write to file directly??

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Here's my suggestion: write to the immediate window AND to a file at the same time. Examples below.

Why make the information first transit in the immediate window, and only then write it to a file from there? That just sounds perversely and uselessly difficult!

```
Dim s As String
Dim n As Integer

n = FreeFile()
Open "C:\test.txt" For Output As #n

s = "Hello, world!"
Debug.Print s ' write to immediate
Print #n, s ' write to file

s = "Long time no see."
Debug.Print s
Write #n, s ' other way of writing to file

Close #n


Dim FSO As Scripting.FileSystemObject
Set FSO = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
Dim txs As Scripting.TextStream
Set txs = FSO.CreateTextFile("C:\test2.txt")
s = "I like chickpeas."
Debug.Print s ' still writing to immediate
txs.WriteLine s ' third way of writing to file
txs.Close
Set txs = Nothing
Set FSO = Nothing
```

Note that this last bit of code requires a reference to be set: Tools > References > checkmark at Microsoft Scripting Runtime.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer! I have a question: is there any advantage/inconvenient in using one of the methods instead of another?

Comment: Yes. I suggest reading up on them and trying them out. Personally, I almost always use the `FileSystemObject` method.

Answer (score 1):

Put this code to immediate window and hit enter to write the List to JSON text in C#.

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Users\m1028200\Desktop\Json2.txt", 
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(resultsAll));
```

Comment: This is a VBA question.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to **use some best-practices-based logging framework like [VBA Logging](http://www.bolterauer.de/consulting/dev/vbatools/vba_logging/VBALogging.html#ImportingSrc)**, which supports file logging or console configurably in parallel etc.

example usage (e.g. in some `Foo.bas` module):

```
Sub MySub()
  Logging.setModulName (Application.VBE.ActiveVBProject.Name)

  Set log = Logging.getNewLogger(Application.VBE.ActiveVBProject.Name)
  Call log.setLoggigParams(Logging.lgALL, True, True, True) ' log  ALL to Console, Buffer, File

  log.logINFO "This is my message ..", "MySub"
End Sub
```

resulting in something like (both in console and `vba_logging.log` file):

```
(16.12.2018 13:08:30)[XlsxMgr::MySub]-INFO:  This is my message ..
```

where the log config file looks like this:

```
## vba_logging.properties
LOG_LEVEL = info
LOG_TO_CONSOLE = True
LOG_TO_BUFFER = True
```