# Visual basic web form. When I hit submit nothing happens.No email is sent. How do I tell what went wrong?

Tags: vb.net, forms, email, visual-studio-debugging

I am using visual studio 2017

- double checked the credentials
- tried using print.debug from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa716276(v=vs.60).aspx)
- tried printing to another file like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13853376/how-do-i-log-vba-debug-print-output-to-a-text-file) said to do
  Don't know how else to figure out why the code isn't working.

  ```
  <%@ Page Language="VB" aspcompat=true Debug="true" %>
  <!DOCTYPE html>

  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head runat="server">
      <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
      <form id="form1" runat="server">
          <div><p>From:&nbsp;<asp:TextBox ID="txtFromAdress" runat="server" Columns="35"></asp:TextBox></p>
              <p>Subject:&nbsp;<asp:TextBox ID="txtSubject" runat="server" Columns="50"></asp:TextBox></p>
              <p>Message:&nbsp;<asp:TextBox ID="txtBody" runat="server" Columns="76" TextMode="multiLine" Rows="6"></asp:TextBox></p>
          <p><asp:Button ID="btnSend" runat="server" Text="Send Mail" /></p> 
          </div>
      </form>
  Debug.print txtFromAdress
  Debug.print txtSubject
  Debug.print txtBody
  </body>
  </html>
  ```

Here is the code behind:

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" aspcompat=true Debug="true" %>

Imports System.Net.Mail

Public Class WebForm1

    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page


    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    End Sub

    Protected Sub btnSend_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSend.Click
        Dim mail As New MailMessage()
        mail.From = New MailAddress(txtFromAdress.Text.Trim)
        mail.To.Add("email@domain.com")
        mail.Subject = txtSubject.Text.Trim()
        mail.Body = txtBody.Text.Trim()
        Debug.print mail
        Dim SmtpClient As New SmtpClient("smtp.office365.com")
        SmtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = False
        SmtpClient.EnableSsl = True
        SmtpClient.Port = 587
        SmtpClient.Credentials = New Net.NetworkCredential("email@domain.com", "pword")
        n = FreeFile()
Open "root/test.txt" For Output As #n
Print #n, mail
        Try
            SmtpClient.Send(mail)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(Err.Number & vbNewLine & ex.Message)
        End Try
```

Comment: Remove aspcompat=true  and try again

Comment: did that and still nothing happened.

Answer (score 1):

Open a command prompt and run the following command:

```
telnet smtp.office365.com 587
```

What is the response? If it produces the desired result then download a tool like Wireshark so that you can analyse the request and response.

Comment: 'telnet' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: Make sure Telnet is installed by following these instructions: https://kb.ctera.com/article/how-to-open-a-telnet-session-on-windows-7-or-windows-8-os-16.html.  Once installed let me know the outcome.

Comment: I talked to my it dept. they said it should work as is and suggested I try and do it in c# instead. so I am abandoning this attempt. Thank you for your help.