# VBA crashing when run but working if I step through

Tags: excel, vba, excel-365

I have the following piece of code that copies and pastes pictures from the worksheet 'RefData' to another worksheet called 'Dashboard' based on a value in a column H/L on the 'Dashboard' worksheet. It has been working fine for a good couple of years but recently when I run it, it runs but then immediately throws me out of excel. If I step through it, it works fine. Any help gratefully received. Please be kind, I am not an expert user.

```
Public Sub UpdatePictures()    
    Dim IconRefresh As Variant  

    Sheets("Dashboard").Select
    If ActiveSheet.Pictures.Count > 1 Then
        ActiveSheet.Shapes.SelectAll
        Selection.Delete
        MsgBox "Pictures Deleted"
    Else
        MsgBox "No Pictures To Delete"
    End If

    Sheets("RefData").Select
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Common")).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Dashboard").Select
    For Each Cell In Range("H6:H15")
        If Cell.Value = "Common" Then
            Cell.Offset(0, 20).Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste
            Selection.ShapeRange.IncrementLeft 15
            Selection.ShapeRange.IncrementTop 3.5
        End If
    Next

    Sheets("RefData").Select
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("HighSpecial(Concern)")).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Dashboard").Select
    For Each Cell In Range("H6:H15")
        If Cell.Value = "HighSpecial(Concern)" Then
            Cell.Offset(0, 20).Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste
            Selection.ShapeRange.IncrementLeft 15
            Selection.ShapeRange.IncrementTop 3.5
        End If
    Next

    Sheets("RefData").Select
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Pass")).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Dashboard").Select
    For Each Cell In Range("L6:L15")
        If Cell.Value = "Pass" Then
            Cell.Offset(0, 19).Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste
            Selection.ShapeRange.IncrementLeft 15
            Selection.ShapeRange.IncrementTop 3.5
        End If
    Next

    Sheets("RefData").Select
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Fail")).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Dashboard").Select
    For Each Cell In Range("L6:L15")
        If Cell.Value = "Fail" Then
            Cell.Offset(0, 19).Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste
            Selection.ShapeRange.IncrementLeft 15
            Selection.ShapeRange.IncrementTop 3.5
        End If
    Next

    Sheets("RefData").Select
    Sheets("Dashboard").Select
    Range("AA5").Select
    
    MsgBox "Pictures Updated"
End Sub
```

I have googled it and have come across others having similar issues, I've checked the answers but don't quite have the VBA skills to know how to fix mine

Comment: Is there no  error message? I wonder if it could be something with your Excel, have you tried this macro on a different PC?

Comment: You could try logging progress to a file to try to determine where the point of failure is. See this thread for specifics on how to do that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13853376/how-do-i-log-vba-debug-print-output-to-a-text-file

Comment: Please install the free and fantastic Rubberduck addin for VBA.  Run the code inspections and pay attention to what you are being told.  Tour current code embodies a number of bad practises for VBA, Rubberduck will help you correct this.

Comment: Also, you should be aware that the active sheets when running your code is not likely to be the same as the active sheet when stepping through your code.  Rubberduck will help you understand how to avoid this problem.

Comment: There is no error message, the code appears to work but then excel just crashes. I have tried it on another pc but still the same issue.

Comment: Unfortunately I am unable to install anything as I don't have the admin rights to do so (NHS work computer)

Comment: Put in some breakpoints and then run it again - at least it will give you an idea of how far it gets before crashing

Comment: Your problems no doubt come from using `Select`, `ActiveSheet`, etc.  Have a read of [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba).

Comment: Pasting pictures in Excel can also be unreliable, particularly if you're doing it in a loop.  Typically that would give you an error message though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have definitely noticed that copy/paste in Excel has become pretty flakey in the past few years, particularly when in a loop and pictures/shapes are involved.

Try this out - a little refactored, and using a separate sub to perform the copy/paste, with re-tries if it fails:

```vb
Option Explicit

Public Sub UpdatePictures()
    Dim wsDash As Worksheet, wsRef As Worksheet
    Dim c As Range, v, shp As Shape
    
    'use worksheet variables...
    Set wsDash = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Dashboard")
    Set wsRef = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("RefData")

    'remove any existing shapes
    If wsDash.Pictures.Count > 1 Then
        wsDash.DrawingObjects.Delete
        MsgBox "Pictures Deleted"
    Else
        MsgBox "No Pictures To Delete"
    End If
    
    'only need to loop each range once...
    For Each c In wsDash.Range("H6:H15").Cells
        v = c.Value
        If v = "Common" Or v = "HighSpecial(Concern)" Then
            'call the Sub to perform the copy/paste...
            CopyPastePicRetry wsRef.Shapes(v), c.Offset(0, 20)
        End If
    Next c
    
    For Each c In wsDash.Range("L6:L15").Cells
        v = c.Value
        If v = "Pass" Or v = "Fail" Then
            CopyPastePicRetry wsRef.Shapes(v), c.Offset(0, 19)
        End If
    Next c
    
    'adjust all shape positions on Dashboard
    For Each shp In wsDash.Shapes
        shp.IncrementLeft 15
        shp.IncrementTop 3.5
    Next shp

    wsDash.Select
    wsDash.Range("AA5").Select
    MsgBox "Pictures Updated"
End Sub

'Try to copy/paste a shape: re-try if fails, up to 20 times
Sub CopyPastePicRetry(shpToCopy As Shape, rngPaste As Range)
    Dim i As Long
    i = 1
    Do While i < 20
        On Error Resume Next
        shpToCopy.Copy
        rngPaste.PasteSpecial
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
            Debug.Print "Copy/Paste failed; try #", i
            DoEvents
            i = i + 1
        Else
            Exit Sub 'copy/paste completed successfully
        End If
        On Error GoTo 0
        i = i + 1
    Loop
    'if got to this point then copy/paste did not succeed
    MsgBox "Failed to copy shape '" & shpToCopy.Name & "' to " & rngPaste.Address
End Sub
```

Comment: That worked a treat! Thank you very much indeed :-)